# Can ViewModel observe its MutableLiveData property?

Tags: kotlin, viewmodel, mutablelivedata

I'm trying to use ViewModels with `LiveData` and `MutableLiveData` in Android for the first time. I have not read all documentation yet.

**My question:**

How can I call `fun applyFilters()` when `val filterByName = MutableLiveData<String>()` was changed from outside (from a `Fragment`).

In .NET MVVM I would just add that call in the setter for `filterByName` property. But how to I do it in with `MutableLiveData`?

I think I should use `MediatorLiveData`, but [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLive) does not explain much.

I was thinking about using the `observer` inside a viewmodel (so it could observe itself), but then I would have to use `AndroidViewModel` instead of `ViewModel`, to get `lifecycleOwner` which is required to observe MutableLiveData...

**My code:**

In my `AssignUhfTagToInventoryItemViewModel() : ViewModel()` (which is shared between few fragments) I have properties like this:

```
/* This is filled only once in SomeViewModel.init() function, always contains all data */
var _items = ArrayList<InventoryItemDto?>()

/* This is filled from _items, contains filtered data */
val items = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<InventoryItemDto?>>().apply { value = ArrayList() }

val filterByName = MutableLiveData<String>().apply { value = "" }
```

And a function like this:

```
fun applyFilters(){
    Log.d(TAG, "ViewModel apply filters called. Current name filter: ${filterByName.value}")
    items.value?.clear()
    val nameFilterLowercase = filterByName.value.toString().lowercase()
    if (!filterByName.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        for (item in _items) {
            val itemNameLowercase = item?.name?.lowercase()
            if (itemNameLowercase?.contains(nameFilterLowercase) == true)
                items.value?.add(item)
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Filter is on, data cached   : ${_items.count()} rows")
        Log.d(TAG, "              data displayed: ${items.value?.count()} rows")
    }
    else {
        items.value?.addAll(_items)
        Log.d(TAG, "Filter is off, data cached   : ${_items.count()} rows")
        Log.d(TAG, "               data displayed: ${items.value?.count()} rows")
    }
}
```

And this is part of my `Fragment` where I use that viewmodel:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val binding = FragmentInventoryItemSelectBinding.bind(view)
    val vm = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())[AssignUhfTagToInventoryItemViewModel::class.java]

    // old school ArrayAdapter 
    val listAdapter = InventoryItemViewAdapter(this.context, vm.items.value)

    binding.lvItems.adapter = listAdapter // old school ListView

    binding.tvFilterByName.addTextChangedListener(AfterTextChangedWatcher {
        
        vm.filterByName.postValue(it)

        /*

            IN MY FRAGMENT I WANT TO AVOID FUNCTION CALL BELOW

        */
        vm.applyFilters() 
        

        listAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated()
        Log.d(TAG, "afterTextChanged: $it")
    })

    vm.items.observe(requireActivity()){
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated()
    }
}
```

Comment: AndroidViewModel only gives you an Application, not a LifecycleOwner, so that wouldn't help. You can use `observeForever` to observe something without a LifecycleOwner, but then it's up to you to remove the observer manually to avoid leaks. But in this case, the correct solution is using a MediatorLiveData or Transformations.map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically? I guess you can but you can use `Transformations.switchMap` to take input from one LiveData and apply them to the source from another.

```
    var _items = MutableLiveData(ArrayList<InventoryItemDto?>())

    val filterByName = MutableLiveData<String>().apply { value = "" }

    val items = Transformations.switchMap(filterByName) { filter -> 
        val nameFilterLowercase = filter.lowercase()
        _items.map { mappedItems -> 
            mappedItems.filter { listItem ->
                listItem.contains(nameFilterLowercase)
            } 
        }
    }

vm.items.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { items ->
    // old school ArrayAdapter 
    val listAdapter = InventoryItemViewAdapter(this.context, items)

    binding.lvItems.adapter = listAdapter // old school ListView
}
```

Comment: What type is `filterByName` in your snippet?

Comment: @Kamil same as yours, (Mutable)LiveData<String>()

Comment: @Kamil Oh, my bad. Extensions in my codebase. Updated the answer.

Comment: I almost got it. But my ArrayAdapter constructor crashes on null pointer exception when I pass `items.value` to it.

Comment: @Kamil You shouldn't access it directly. LiveData will have no value if no one is observing them. All you need to do is change the filter and items will change.

Comment: But I need `ArrayList` instance for ArrayAdapter... I'm not using `RecyclerView` because... I don't remember why, but I had a reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248858/discussion-between-thelibrarian-and-kamil).